# Need to get value after Domain name in url using java

Tags: java, rest-assured

We are getting url from JSON Response and which we open in in Chrome.The page loads , there is submit button which we click then it redirect to url as :-
https://www.google.com/AB1234

We need the need to retrieve only "AB1234" value from url.

tried following code to get value ="AB1234"

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            int index=url.lastIndexOf("/");
            String result = url.substring(0,index);
```

but here getting initial part of url:https://www.google.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call substring function with    `index +1` .

Try below code :

```
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    int index = url.lastIndexOf("/");
    String result = url.substring(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse a URI, it's likely a good idea to use a URI parser.

Given http://example.com/bar

```
 String path = URI.create(driver.getCurrentUrl()).getPath();
```

will get you '/bar'.

Given http://example.com/bar/mumble the same code gets '/bar/mumble'.  It's unclear from your question whether this is what you want. Nevertheless, you should at least start the parse as above.